# Modifying class attributes at runtime

Tags: c#, petapoco

I have a postgres database with several schemas.

And schemas are also created at runtime while the app runs.

These schemas have a fixed set of tables, named like `table1`, `table2`.

In Petopoco i have to decorate by Poco classes with the table attribute.

I do it like

```
[TableName("schema1.table1")]
[PrimaryKey("id")]
class SomePoco {
    [Column("id")]public int Id { get; set; }
//other properties
}
```

I want the schema part of the attribute to be changed at runtime, since I am creating schemas at runtime.

Is there a possibility for this, or is there any other way I can use a single POCO over multiple schemas.

Comment: You cannot change attribute at runtime. Looking at source code of PetaPoco and there is no way to do that. Looks like you have chosen non-suitable ORM for your task.

Comment: I have never used PetaPoco, but in Entity framework it is fairly simple to specify the schema at runtime. If your ORM does not support this you might want to reconsider your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can't change the attribute, there are a few different ways to get what you want, depending on what info your code has and how you want to write your code.

One approach is to remove the `TableName` attribute from your POCO and specify the whole query in your SQL. So instead of just `db.Fetch<SomePoco>()` you might do something like:

```cs
var schemaName = "schema1";
var tableName = "table1";
db.Fetch<SomePoco>($"select * from {schemaName}.{tableName}");
```

You could also use a custom mapper to help you get what you want. A PetaPoco mapper interprets between POCO information and table/column names, so you can use it to make changes on the way to the database.

```cs
[TableName("table1")]
[PrimaryKey("id")]
class SomePoco {
    [Column("id")]public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class SchemaMapper : ConventionMapper
{    
    private string _schema;
    public SchemaMapper(string schema)
    {
       _schema = schema;
    }

    public override TableInfo GetTableInfo(Type pocoType)
    {
        var ti = base.GetTableInfo(pocoType);
        // prepend the schema to the table name
        ti.TableName = $"{_schema}.{ti.TableName}";
        return ti;
    }
}

using var db = new Database(myConnection, new SchemaMapper("schema1"));
db.Fetch<SomePoco>();

// SELECT schema1.table1.id from schema1.table1
```

If you make `Schema` a public property instead of a private field, you could even change the schema after you've created the `Database` object, by setting `((SchemaMapper)db.DefaultMapper).Schema` later on.

(By the way, instead of having to explicitly set `ColumnName` properties on all your POCOs just to lowercase them, you can also have your mapper do that for you  by adding `InflectColumnName = (i, cn) => cn.ToLower();` to your mapper's constructor. This will automatically turn property `Id` into column `id`.)